# Docker-machine's container contact application on Mac host

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-machine

I have a Mac laptop with docker-machine's running a container with nginx and several other apps on other containers. I can contact my apps through the host vm -> through nginx container -> into app container.

I would like to have applications contact another application running on my Mac (for debugging). Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. One simple way is use `--link` option

```
docker run -ti --link mysql:mysql <Docker_image>
```

#### Notes:

As recommended by @Matt, you can also build the network with latest docker.

refer [User-defined networks](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/dockernetworks/#user-defined-networks:c714994348fc0293afe965e34575ee6d)

Comment: I supposed the owner didn't say it need be vm hosted. Maybe your thinking is too complex.

Comment: oh.. fyi since 1.9 the same feature set is now available (and recommended) via [User-defined networks](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/dockernetworks/#user-defined-networks:c714994348fc0293afe965e34575ee6d) without the niggles of having a first container started to link to and losing links etc. `--link` has not been deprecated though.

Comment: Thanks, @Matt. I prefer the docker way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can contact services on the docker-machine VM host via TCP/IP. The default docker virtual machines have two network interfaces attached to them.

#### Adapter 1

The first network adapter is attached to the NAT network for internet access. This provides a route to the main adapters address on your laptop, which is normally `en0`

```
→ ifconfig en0 | grep "inet "
    inet 192.168.10.33 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.10.255
```

You can use this address from inside your docker VM or containers to access services that are running on your mac.

```
docker@default-docker:~$ curl http://192.168.10.33:3000/time
{"time":{"now":1454987348431,"start":1454635891001}}
```

#### Adapter 2

There is a second Host-only adapter used for docker management. The *Name* of the Host-only  adapter in VirtualBox will map to an interface on your host.

```
→ VBoxManage showvminfo default | grep "NIC 2"
NIC 2:           MAC: 0800270D841E, Attachment: Host-only Interface 'vboxnet3', Cable connected: on, Trace: off (file: none), Type: 82540EM, Reported speed: 0 Mbps, Boot priority: 0, Promisc Policy: deny, Bandwidth group: none
```

Your mac will have a corresponding interface

```
→ ifconfig vboxnet3
vboxnet3: flags=8943<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 0a:00:27:00:00:03 
    inet 192.168.99.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.99.255
```

You can also use this address.

```
docker@default-docker:~$ curl http://192.168.99.1:3000/time
{"time":{"now":1454987348590,"start":1454635891001}}
```

The host only adapter address is useful if your network IP changes and you need to configure something static in a container, the host adapter address' will remain consistent (unless you destroy your vm, then it might change)